# Problems trying to write data to a file. error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, external, symbols, lnk2019

I'm getting an error:

> 1>  Source.cpp 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "void __cdecl saveToFile(char const * const,struct Task *
>   const,int)" (?saveToFile@@YAXQBDQAUTask@@H@Z) referenced in function
>   _main 1>C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Coding Stuff\C++ programs\CS162 HW\cs_162_hw_2\Debug\cs_162_hw_2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved externals

and it only happens when i attempt to run my saveToFile function. Here is the code for that function:

```
void saveToFile(const char fileName[MAX_CHAR], const Task list[], int size)
{
ofstream out;

out.open(fileName);
if(!out)
{
    cerr << "Fail to open " << fileName << " for writing!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

int index;
for(index=0; index < size; index++)
{
    out << list[index].course << ';' << list[index].description << ';' <<       list[index].date << endl;
}

out.close();
 }
```

Comment: And the source file this function is in, is actually included in your project? Is it compiled and linked with the other files?

Comment: Is saveToFile part of a  class or a standalone function?

Comment: I suggest you rewrite function signature to: `void saveToFile(const std::string& fileName, const std::vector<Task>& task_list)`

Comment: @billz Then he will get compiler errors where his other code tries to call `saveToFile`... I don't think you are helping.

Comment: Are you using VS?  You need to add the .cpp file which contains this code to your project, there is a straightforward command for that I think.

Comment: @MattPhillips won't much to change at all. Mixing C/C++ always makes code harder to maintain than simply change to better pure c++ code.

Comment: All my functions are in my 1 and only source code file for this project. Everything runs fine if i comment out the saveToFile function. I have a function that reads the data from the txt file and that works, so i know my program can see the txt file. billz it is just a function not part of a class. And my teacher said no strings and no vectors. only char arrays.

Comment: Do you define `saveToFile` _before_ or _after_ you call it? It must be declared (i.e. prototyped) or defined before you call it.

Comment: Yes i am using visual studio 2012. The cpp file is in my project of course...

Comment: @billz Sure in principle but obviously you're introducing a whole new, tangential project here.  No code in the body of `saveToFile` would need to be changed but going to STL there could possibly trigger a rewrite of the entire program.

Comment: i have a prototype before my main function, and a definition after main. Just like all my other function (and they work fine) so i don't think it has to do with that.

Comment: "and a definition after main"  Humor us and put the definition ahead of main, and see what happens.

Comment: How does the prototype look like? It has to be exactly the same as the definition

Comment: I put it before main, same error.

Comment: prototype: void saveToFile(const char fileName[MAX_CHAR], Task list[], int size);

Comment: Yup the prototype didn't have the 'const' that the definition had. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is still unresolved, you should add the path to lib files in visual studio project

properties > Linkers > Additional Library Directories

I faced similar issue and resolved by doing this